# Proving postulate about a property fo spherical vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, spheres

Assume we have $X, Y$ constant unit vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$

I postulate that the maximum of the function:

$(V \cdot X) (V \cdot Y)$

I reached by the halfway vector between $X,Y$ i.e at the vector $V_0 = slerp(X,Y, 0.5)$

To try to prove it I tried finding the critical point of the derivative, i.e:

$(V'\cdot X)(V\cdot Y) + (V\cdot X)(V'\cdot Y)$

But that is leading me down a rabbit hole I don't seem to be able to get out of.

Comment: Derivative with respect to $V$? But you'd better constrain $V$ to be a unit vector as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, choose $X=(1,0,0)$ and $Y=(\cos\phi_0,\sin\phi_0,0)$. Then (assuming $V$ is also unit vector), you can write $V$ in polar coordinates as $V=(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta)$. Then your expression becomes
$$\sin\theta\cos\phi(\sin\theta\cos\phi\cos\phi_0+\sin\theta\sin\phi\sin\phi_0)=\sin^2\theta\cos\phi\cos(\phi-\phi_0)$$
If you want the maximum, you get $\theta=\pi/2$, so it's in the same plane.
Also $$\frac d{d\phi}\cos\phi\cos(\phi-\phi_0)=-\sin(2\phi-\phi_0)=0$$
so $$\phi=\frac{\phi_0}2$$
You will need to consider separately the case where $\phi_0=\pi$